# asp.net.vb Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, vb.net, sqldatareader

I am not sure why this code doesn't work
I have follow according to the table field data and it I am still unable to get the SQL Datareader to work. I have checked the tables and all datafields, everything is correct. But I still am unable to read data from the database. Help T.T

```
    Dim connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CleanOneConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim myConn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    myConn.Open()
    Dim cmd = "Select * from [Member] where Email = @Email"
    Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand(cmd, myConn)
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailBox.Text)
    Dim objReader As SqlDataReader

    objReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()
    objReader.Read()
    Result.Text = " " 'initialise label to show correct message for available or found


    'Check the reader see if any  record found matching WHERE
    If (objReader.Read()) Then
        'read=true, check Password
        'Dim tpassword As String = objReader.GetString(5)
        'If tpassword = passwordBox.Text Then
        'Result.Text = "** Login Succcessful **"
        Result.Text = objReader.GetString(1)
        'Else
        'Result.Text = "Invalid Password" & objReader.GetString(5) & passwordBox.Text
        'End If
        'reader=false, no such records matching WHERE
    Else
        Result.Text = objReader.GetString(1)
    End If
    myCmd.Dispose()
    myConn.Dispose()
```

Comment: When you run the raw SQL (use SQL profiler to see), do you get any rows back from the database? Is it going into the loop?

Comment: Fot this one, no, but I am sure that I can get rows via the SQLDataReader, for this one, I can't seems to retrieve any rows. I have already tried countless times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing with MySql: I get an error that the SQL syntax is not correct.

I then removed the [ ] and it works.

How is that with SqlServer? Try at least, i'd say.